# session variable between 2 divs on same page?

Tags: php, session

im trying to pass a session between 2 div on the same page.
i have links, when i click on one i want the id to pass to the other div to populate it with the info from the link, but it doesnt pass!!

this is the code from my links div

```
$q =mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
$data = $row['image'];
$file = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1);
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];

echo"<div class='homedogs'>",
"<a href='merchandise.php' class='productchoice'>",
"<img class='nailthumb-container3' src='$file' alt='{$row['name']}. Image' />",
"</a>",
"<br />",
'NAME: ',$row['name'],"<br />",'PRICE: ',$row['price'],
"</div>";
}
}
```

and this is other div that i want to use the session in

```
include 'inc/connect.php';
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM products WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'") or  
                 die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
$data = $row['image'];
$file = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1);
echo"<div class='rehomediv'>",
"<img class='nailthumb-container2' src='$file' alt='{$row['name']}. Image' />","<br 
  />",
"<div class='nameagesex'>",
"<div class='item_name'>{$row['name']}</div>",
"<br />",
"<span class='item_price'>{$row['price']}</span>",
"</div>",
"<div class='description'>",
 nl2br($row['description']),
 "</div>",
</div>;
```

im sure its simple enought but i cant get it! can anyone help? 
thanks

EDIT!!!!!

on page load, pid is not set so i get an error, is there anyway to have it that if pid is not set then it just display the last record?

for anyone confused by this edit, check the accepted answer..

Comment: You have to use session_start(); on both pages

Comment: sorry i omitted that bit. i use session_start(). but this is only one page. im wanting to pass the session between 2 divs on the same page.

Comment: You mean the same request? A simple variable would suffice for that.

Comment: If it's on the same page, just use $row['id']; You don't have to make a session variable for that..

Comment: ok, i didnt need to use a session! but its still not changing. i want to click a link, have the page refresh and show the data from that link in the second div. how could i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `$_SESSION['id']` multiple times inside a `while` loop. This will end up keeping only the last value, provided that you do `session_start()`, as you claim you do.

If you want this to work, don't use `$_SESSION`, but a `GET` query instead. Change your link-producing code to:

```
"<a href='merchandise.php?pid={$row['id']}' class='productchoice'>"
```

...and, in `merchandise.php` check `$_GET['pid']` to determine the product id being requested:

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']))
  // show corresponding product (your second listing)
else
  // show something else, i.e. the product catalog (your first listing)
```

Comment: if `pid` is not set, just use an if / else statement: `if(isset($_GET['pid'])) { //do x } else { //do y }`